# How to retrieve data from .aspx page using Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I am looking to access data from a .aspx website with a number of fields where parameters need to be entered. The data will be further analyzed in Pandas. I'm obviously missing some steps here, so any help would be appreciated. The website is https://www.cocorahs.org/ViewData/StationPrecipSummary.aspx

I'm trying a simple method using the Python library Requests, getting the json, and converting to a DataFrame.

```
parameters = {'Station 1':'MD-BL-13','Start Date':'8/01/2019','End Date':'08/10/2017'}
response = requests.get('https://www.cocorahs.org/ViewData/StationPrecipSummary.aspx', params=parameters)
data = response.json()
pd.read_json(data)
```

I would like to get a DataFrame with columns 'Date' and 'Precip mm' with data from the time period requested. A check of response.content shows that the parameters are not correctly taken, as only the content of the web page before a query has been entered appears.

Comment: You need to use something like selenium or scrapy for this

Comment: I got started on Selenium, but was hoping there was a simpler way! Good to know...

Comment: I’m viewing this on mobile so forgive me for asking: should this be a POST request requests.post(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find ASP.NET sites to be a pain in the ass to deal with, but here's a solution with pandas and requests-html.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd


with HTMLSession() as s:

    r = s.get('https://www.cocorahs.org/ViewData/StationPrecipSummary.aspx')
    hiddens = r.html.find('input[name=__VIEWSTATE]', first=True).attrs.get('value')

    payload = {
        '__EVENTTARGET': '',
        '_VIEWSTATE': hiddens,
        'obsSwitcher:ddlObsUnits': 'usunits',
        'tbStation1': 'MD-BL-13',
        'ucDateRangeFilter:dcStartDate': '8/1/2019',
        'ucDateRangeFilter_dcStartDate_p': '2019-8-1-0-0-0-0',
        'ucDateRangeFilter:dcEndDate': '8/10/2019',
        'ucDateRangeFilter_dcEndDate_p': '2019-8-10-0-0-0-0',
        'btnSubmit': 'Get Summary'
        }


    r = s.post('https://www.cocorahs.org/ViewData/StationPrecipSummary.aspx', data=payload)
    table = r.html.find('table.Grid', first=True)
    df = pd.read_html(table.html, header=0)[0]
    print(df)


          Date Precip in.
0   08/01/2019       0.00
1   08/02/2019       0.00
2   08/03/2019       0.00
3   08/04/2019       0.00
4   08/05/2019       0.00
5   08/06/2019       0.00
6   08/07/2019          T
7   08/08/2019       1.73
8   08/09/2019         --
9   08/10/2019         --
10    Totals :   1.73 in.
```

Comment: It's not using beautifulsoup to parse HTML, instead, I'm using requests_html. 
   response.html.find returns a list of found elements, first=True returns the first item in that list